# How to make sympi arrange formula so that the highest order coefficient in the numerator is one

Tags: python, sympy, differential-equations

I am using sympy and python to solve some equations.  I am trying to arrange an equation so that the coefficient in terms of the highest degree is +1.  For example the following code produces the output

```
Km, Kb, L, s, R, J, b = sym.symbols("Km, Kb, L, s, R, J, b")
G1 = Km / (L * s + R)
G2 = 1 / (J * s + b)
Msys = (G1 * G2) / (1 + G1 * G2 * Kb)
Msys = sym.expand(Msys)
Msys = sym.simplify(Msys)
Msys = sym.collect(Msys, s)

print(Msys)

#outputs Km/(J*L*s**2 + Kb*Km + R*b + s*(J*R + L*b))
```

I need to get rid of coefficients in front of s**2 (ie set to 1).  This would normally be done by dividing both the top and bottom by J*L.  I found a sympi function called monic that is supposed to do this but it only works on the numerator.

What is the best solution to this problem?

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 1):

This is not an ideal solution because it gets the formula in the form that I need it.  Basically I split the formula up into top and bottom, then I multiply by 1 / (J * L) the coefficients in front of the highest degree variable.

```
Km, Kb, L, R, J, b, Gc, Ain, Amp, Hoi, s = sym.symbols("Km, Kb, L, R, J, b, Gc, Ain, Amp, Hoi, s")
G1 = 1/ (L * s + R)
print(G1)
G2 = 1 / (J * s + b)
print(G2)

Msys = (Km * G1 * G2) / (1 + Km * G1 * G2 * Kb)
Msys = sym.expand(Msys)
Msys = sym.simplify(Msys)
Msys = sym.collect(Msys, s)
g3 = Msys * ((1/(J*L))/(1/(J*L)))
print(g3)
top, bot = Msys.as_numer_denom()
top = top * (1/(J*L))
print(top)
bot = bot * (1/(J*L))
bot = sym.expand(bot)
bot = sym.collect(bot, s)

print(bot)

Msys = top * 1/bot
```

While this solution worked it is not ideal, because of its complexity.  I could probably further develop it and make it into a function I can reuse, but there must be an easier way